# express 4, inconsistent view count in sample code

Tags: node.js, express

https://github.com/expressjs/session

The following code is copied from req.session

Using express 4, **the problem is**

The views count is working in firefox. Every time, the views increase once after a page refresh.

The views count increases twice, in chrome and opera. That is not right?

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true, 
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session;
  if (sess.views) {
    //test
    debugger;

    sess.views = sess.views + 1;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>');
    res.end();
  } else {
    sess.views = 1;
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!');
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to:

```
app.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
  var sess = req.session;
  if (sess.views) {
    //test
    debugger;

    sess.views = sess.views + 1;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>');
    res.end();
  } else {
    sess.views = 1;
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is working, but I don't know why the sample code is not wroking. I just read this: expressjs.com/api.html#app.use. app.use(..) is default to "/", so it should work.